# wcf message layer security username authentication with custom validator

Tags: wcf, validation

Where is the best place to store the username and password if I don't necessarily want to store it in the database when using a custom validator?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have 1 or 2 user MAX you can store them in the app.config or maybe in the reg file but if you think you will have more, then the DB will be the best choice. It cost almost nothing to get them from a SQL server.Also, take a look at this : [Storing and encrypting SMTP credentials in the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458733/storing-and-encrypting-smtp-credentials-in-the-registry)