# WCF Custom Username Validator: Why is this code considered so unsecure?

Tags: wcf, security, wcf-security

I'm writing a WCF service and want to use a CustomUserNameValidator. I found the following code in the MSDN website. I guess usually one would check the username and password from a database, which makes sense. But why is the below hardcoded code considered so unsecure?

```
// This method validates users. It allows in two users, test1 and test2 
// with passwords 1tset and 2tset respectively.
// This code is for illustration purposes only and 
// must not be used in a production environment because it is not secure.    
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
{
if (null == userName || null == password)
    throw new ArgumentNullException();

if (!(userName == "test1" && password == "1tset") && !(userName == "test2" && password == "2tset"))
    throw new FaultException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
}
```

I will have maybe 1 or 2 usernames (shared among many clients, it doesn't matter which client the request comes from). I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987931/wcf-message-layer-security-username-authentication-with-custom-validator) post which talks about putting the username/passwords in a config file. But don't understand how that's much different than hardcoding the two passwords in.
Could somebody please enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting aside the limited number of credentials you have the password stored in clear text, so if someone gets hold of your assembly the password is there for all to see. The config file option at least you can tell ASP.NET to encrypt that part of the configuration file so, should it leak, it's worthless.